# What is meant by this sentence about JSON in the Postgresql docs?

Tags: json, postgresql, theory

Can someone provide an example of what this sentence is trying to convey?  I am not sure I understand it.

From the Postgresql website (docs) :

"JSON documents should each represent an atomic datum that business rules dictate cannot reasonably be further subdivided into smaller datums that could be modified independently"

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

Comment: Why did you tag this as "MongoDB"?!?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about it? When you are not sure you understood it correctly, what do you think it means? We can not write a helpful answer without a hint what you do and don't already know. For example, we don't know if you know what an "atomic datum" is or what the general best practices regarding database normalization (which are hinted at with "reasonably be further subdivided into smaller datums") are.

Comment: What is an example of an "atomic datum" and what is an example of a document that "cannot reasonably be further subdivided" and what is an example of a document that could be "further subdivided" ?  @Philipp

Comment: That's all application-specific.

Answer (score 0):

The principle here is that in PostgreSQL, updating a json document requires that the json document and the whole row it's contained in<sup>*</sup> be updated. So you should generally keep them small and split them up where appropriate.

For example, instead of a json document like:

```
{
"someobjects": [
  {
     "a": 1,
     ...
  },
  {
     "b": 2,
     ...
  },
  ...
  ],
"otherobjects": [
  ...
  ]
}
```

it's probably better to normalize it into two tables `someobjects` and `otherobjects`, each of which stores individual `someobject` json documents.

Use `json` where the data is freeform or variable-structure. Normalize where it isn't.

---

<sup>*</sup> PostgreSQL can often avoid re-writing copies of other large fields in the same row if they're stored out-of-line using `TOAST`, which happens automatically where appropriate.

Comment: When you say, 'keep them small and split them up' could that also mean to use multiple json columns instead of one column and dumping all the json into it?

Comment: @mgcdanny There might be times that's appropriate, but usually I wouldn't think so. It's more that if you have a json document containing a 200000-element array of objects you probably want to store it as 200000 rows in a table where each object is a separate row, not a single database row with a monster json document in it. That sort of thing. There is no hard and fast rule; it's about tradeoffs and depends on the application needs and why you're using json in the first place.